# T-SQL Syntax for SCD Type 2

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, data-warehouse, scd2

I am currently trying to complete the final part of a query that loads scd type 2 data into a dimension.
Based on the data provided below I would like to produce an output that can be inserted into a dimension in addition to 
expiring old records and tracking history etc. The data is such that I have the most current records where attributes have changed. The changed values are found in Lookup columns along with and dateOfchange i.e. the date the change took place. This dateOfchange should obviously become the validTo date of the most current record.

The sample data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tstDimPortfolio
(
[ID][INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
[UPI] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[MF_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[BH_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[CR_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ValidFrom][varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[ValidTo][varchar](10) NULL,
[IsCurrent] [CHAR] (1) NULL,
[DateofChange] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupMF_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupBH_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupCR_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
) 

INSERT INTO #tstDimPortfolio
SELECT 'B06531','B06531','','B06531','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120101','','B06531', ''
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BLI003','','BLI003','BBL_WORLD','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120102','BLI004','',    ''UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BLI003','','BLI003','BBL_WORLD','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120103','BLI005','',    ''UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BLI027','BLI027','L147','BBL_GBN','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120104','','L146', ''
```

With this data the new output should be

```
UPI MF_CODE   BH_Code  CR_Code   ValidFrom  ValidTo      IsCurrent
_______________________________________________________________________
B06531  B06531  B06531               20111230   20120101        N
B06531  B06531  B06531  B06531       20120101   NULL            Y
BLI003  BLI003  BBL_WORLD            20111230   20120102        N
BLI003  BLI004  BLI003  BBL_WORLD    20120102   20120103        N
BLI003  BLI005  BLI003  BBL_WORLD    20120103   NULL            Y
BLI027  BLI027  L147    BBL_GBN      20111230   20120104        N
BLI027  BLI027  L146    BBL_GBN      20120104   NULL            Y
```

any ideas

Comment: @Mitch Wheat first of all it has to be done in t-sql. A the moment we do not have ssis so it as has done via stored procedures. I have tried join the table to itself with the following:

Comment: @Mitch Wheat first of all it has to be done in t-sql. A the moment we do not have ssis so it as has done via stored procedures. I have tried join the table to itself on the upi and dateOfchange < dateOfchange. I am able to create the expire the current row for each UPI and create the next row but i do not know how to create the subsequent rows with all the previous changes.

Comment: when I said "what have you tried? " I meant show us what you have already written.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to what your natural key is on this table.  Is it "UPI?"  If so, you have two records (BLI003) with the same UPI but they both are active, which should never be the case.

Anyway, assume it's UPI.  If we want to update B06531, get your updates into a table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tstDimPortfolioUpdates
(
[ID][INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
[UPI] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[MF_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[BH_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[CR_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ValidFrom][varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[ValidTo][varchar](15) NULL,
[IsCurrent] [CHAR] (1) NULL,
[DateofChange] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupMF_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupBH_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupCR_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
) 


INSERT INTO #tstDimPortfolioUpdates
SELECT 'B06531','B06531','B06531','B06531','20120102',NULL,'Y','20120102','','B06531', ''
```

Set any records that should no longer be active by changing the ValidTo, IsCurrent and DateOfChange values

```
UPDATE dp
SET ValidTo = '20120101', IsCurrent = 'N', DateOfChange = '20120101'
FROM #tstDimPortfolio dp
INNER JOIN #tstDimPortfolioUpdates up ON dp.UPI = up.UPI
AND dp.IsCurrent = 'Y'
```

Insert the new records

```
INSERT INTO #tstDimPortfolio (UPI, MF_Code, BH_Code, CR_Code, ValidFrom, ValidTo
    ,IsCurrent, DateOfChange, LookupMF_Code, LookupBH_Code, LookupCR_Code)
SELECT UPI, MF_Code, BH_Code, CR_Code, ValidFrom, ValidTo
    ,IsCurrent, DateOfChange, LookupMF_Code, LookupBH_Code, LookupCR_Code
FROM #tstDimPortfolioUpdates
```

Double-check that the update is correct

```
SELECT * FROM #tstDimPortfolio
ORDER BY UPI
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the desired result using a recursive cte. UPI is the natural key. However  the events actually come from a separate file which is pivoted and joined on to the dimension. (BLI003) had 2 rows as it had two events. the sql was as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE #tstDimPortfolio
 (
[ID][INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
[UPI] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[MF_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[BH_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[CR_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[ValidFrom][varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[ValidTo][varchar](10) NULL,
[IsCurrent] [CHAR] (1) NULL,
[DateofChange] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupMF_CODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupBH_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,
[LookupCR_Code] [varchar](10) NULL,


) 

INSERT INTO #tstDimPortfolio
SELECT 'B06531','B06531','','B06531','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120101','','B06531', ''UNION ALL
SELECT 'BLI003','','BLI003','BBL_WORLD','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120102','BLI004','', ''UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BLI003','','BLI003','BBL_WORLD','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120103','','BLI005', ''UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BLI027','BLI027','L147','BBL_GBN','20111230',NULL,'Y','20120104','','L146', ''





SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPI ORDER BY UPI, DateofChange) Sequence,
    UPI, 
    CASE WHEN LookupMF_CODE <> '' THEN LookupMF_CODE ELSE MF_CODE END MF_CODE, 
    CASE WHEN LookupMF_CODE <> '' THEN LookupBH_Code ELSE BH_Code END BH_Code, 
    CASE WHEN LookupCR_Code <> '' THEN LookupCR_Code ELSE CR_Code  END CR_Code, 
    ValidFrom, ValidTo, IsCurrent, DateofChange,
    LookupMF_CODE,
    LookupBH_CODE,
    LookupCR_CODE
INTO #Dimension_Table
FROM #tstDimPortfolio


;WITH AddedDim AS
(SELECT * FROM 

(
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPI ORDER BY UPI, DateofChange) Sequence,
UPI,
CASE WHEN LookupMF_CODE <> '' THEN LookupMF_CODE ELSE MF_CODE END MF_CODE, 
CASE WHEN LookupBH_CODE <> '' THEN LookupBH_Code ELSE BH_Code END BH_Code, 
CASE WHEN LookupCR_Code <> '' THEN LookupCR_Code ELSE CR_Code  END CR_Code, 
DateofChange AS ValidFrom, 
ValidTo, 
IsCurrent 
FROM #tstDimPortfolio
)A
WHERE SEQUENCE = 1

UNION ALL
SELECT  
DT.Sequence
, DT.UPI
,CASE WHEN DT.LookupMF_CODE <> '' THEN DT.LookupMF_CODE ELSE DM.MF_CODE END MF_CODE
,CASE WHEN DT.LookupBH_CODE <> '' THEN DT.LookupBH_Code ELSE DM.BH_Code END BH_Code 
,CASE WHEN DT.LookupCR_Code <> '' THEN DT.LookupCR_Code ELSE DM.CR_Code  END CR_Code
,DT.DateofChange AS ValidFrom 
,DT.ValidTo 
,DT.IsCurrent 
FROM #Dimension_Table dt inner join
AddedDim dm
on DT.UPI = DM.UPI
AND dt.Sequence = DM.Sequence + 1 
)
```

SELECT * 
   INTO #temp
   FROM AddedDim